# How to get the size of the file using get-itemproperty in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell-v4.0

I have a file having data around 5GB. I tried to get size of the file using `get-content $path2 | Measure-Object` method. But its taking more time as `Get-Content cmdlet` is present.

Is there method to get the size of this kind of file very quickly. I would like to get the file size using Properties of a file using Get-ItemProperty.

Can anyone suggest me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you MUST use get-itemproperty?

in that case I guess I would write:  get-itemproperty .\filename.txt -name length

...and then parse the output or pipe it.

.

A better choice would be to use the

get-childitem command and parse the output from that. Something like:

get-childitem .\filename.txt | select length

...but this gives you an extra line that you don't want, so refine it with

get-childitem .\filename.txt | % ( $_.length )

yeah, that looks better.